# Karma error StaticInjectorError -> how to correctly provide custom pipe to component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular8

I'm trying to write tests for component where I'm using customly written pipe, but I'm getting error from karma, that I'm not providing it correctly. Project is building/working with no errors (seems that everything is provided correctly), but for tests, it seems that something is off. What's wrong and how to fix it? :? (some components using it only in *html* some of them uses in services etc, so it seems that the problem is not in *providers: [AppTranslatePipe]*

```
Failed: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AppTranslatePipe -> 
TranslateService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AppTranslatePipe -> TranslateService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
```

.html (part where I'm using this pipe)

```
<button
  mat-raised-button
  mat-dialog-close
  class="close">
  {{ 'common.cancel' | appTranslate }}
</button>
```

.module imported pipe's module, because I'm using it on html

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserSettingsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    AppTranslateModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    UserSettingsComponent,
  ]
})
export class UserSettingsModule { }
```

.component.ts (because I'm using also this pipe in *showNotificationOnSubmit* function, I need to set AppTranslatePipe via *providers*, which maybe is the problem? :?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-user-settings',
  templateUrl: './user-settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-settings.component.sass'],
  providers: [ AppTranslatePipe ]
})
export class UserSettingsComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserSettingsComponent>,
    private translationService: TranslationService,
    private globalNotificationsService: GlobalNotificationsService,
    private appTranslatePipe: AppTranslatePipe,
  ) { }

  showNotificationOnSubmit(
    isNewLangSetted: boolean,
    isNewPasswordSetted: boolean
  ): void {
    this.globalNotificationsService.addTypedNotification(
      this.appTranslatePipe.transform('user-settings.success.update'),
      NotificationTypeEnum.success
    );
  }
}
```

*spec.ts

```
fdescribe('UserSettingsComponent', () => {
  let component: UserSettingsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserSettingsComponent>;

  let translationService: jasmine.SpyObj<TranslationService>;
  let appTranslatePipe: jasmine.SpyObj<AppTranslatePipe>;
  let userService: jasmine.SpyObj<UserService>;
  let globalNotificationsService: jasmine.SpyObj<GlobalNotificationsService>;
  const fb: FormBuilder = new FormBuilder();
  let matDialogRef: jasmine.SpyObj<MatDialogRef<UserSettingsComponent>>;

  const MOCK_TRANSLATIONS: ILocale[] = [
    {
      Id: 0,
      Key: 'key',
      Snapshot: null,
      Title: 'title-1',
      TotalCount: 0
    }
  ];

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UserSettingsComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        LoaderModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        AppTranslateModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TranslationService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('TranslationService', [
            'getTranslationList',
            'updateLanguage',
            'setLanguage'
          ])
        },
        {
          provide: UserService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', [
            'updatePassword',
          ])
        },
        {
          provide: GlobalNotificationsService,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('GlobalNotificationsService', [
            'addTypedNotification',
          ])
        },
        { provide: FormBuilder, useValue: fb },
        {
          provide: MatDialogRef,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('MatDialogRef', [
            'close'
          ]),
        },
        {
          provide: AppTranslatePipe,
          useValue: jasmine.createSpyObj('AppTranslatePipe', [
            'transform'
          ]),
        },
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    translationService = TestBed.get(TranslationService);
    appTranslatePipe = TestBed.get(AppTranslatePipe);
    userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
    globalNotificationsService = TestBed.get(GlobalNotificationsService);
    matDialogRef = TestBed.get(MatDialogRef);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserSettingsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

  fit('should create', () => {
    translationService.getTranslationList.and.returnValue(
      of([])
    );

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    expect(translationService.getTranslationList)
      .toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

pipe itself:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { TranslationService } from '../../services/translation/translation.service';
import { ILocale } from '../../models/locale.model';

@Pipe({
  name: 'appTranslate',
  pure: false
})
export class AppTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    private translationService: TranslationService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
  ) { }

  transform(
    fileKey: string,
    dbKey?: string
  ) {
    if (!fileKey) {
      return '';
    }

    const currentLang: ILocale = this.translationService.getLanguage();
    if (currentLang) {
      const dbTranslation: string = this.translationService.getDBTranslation_byKey(dbKey);
      if (dbKey && dbTranslation) {
        return dbTranslation;
      } else {
        return this.translate.instant(fileKey) + '\`';  
      }
    } else {
      return this.translate.instant(fileKey) + '\`';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Pipes are mentioned in `declarations` and not `providers`.

Comment: @user what do you mean? if I add as `provider` in module, then I would get error saying `Failed: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'appTranslate' could not be found ("`

Comment: Well it needs to be in the ```providers``` array because unfortunately the pipe seems to be injected in some components not just used inside the html. The problem is that there is no mock for the translation service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you added the real pipe as a dependency to your test (which you cannot avoid if you have a provider declared at the component level) you need to make sure that all the dependencies for that pipe are available inside your test.

So you would need a mock for your `TranslateService` which is injected into your `AppTranslatePipe` and declare that inside the `TestBed` `providers` array

Answer (score 1):

As the error is yelling, your `AppTranslatePipe` require `TranslateService` as it dependency, you need to provide it to TestBed also:

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ....
      providers:[
      ....
      TranslateService
      ]
      ...
```